# Vector bundle under Blow up

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Is there any reference for following result? (It seems it is known for surface case)

If $X$ be a compact complex manifold and $\tilde X\to X$ be its
blow-up at some point, then every holomorphic vector bundle on $\tilde X$ can be
turned into a pull-back form $X$ which is twisted by a line bundle after finitely
many [elementary transformations](http://www.seminariomatematico.unito.it/rendiconti/cartaceo/44-4/1.pdf) along the exceptional divisor.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by elementary transformations along the exceptional divisor?

Comment: I added a link  for the definition of elementary transformations http://www.seminariomatematico.unito.it/rendiconti/cartaceo/44-4/1.pdf

Comment: As Maruyama says, elementary transformations work only for small dimensions. So, I doubt any general result as you want for arbitrary dimensions exist.

Comment: Do you assume the blow up center is smooth?